# Java Hibernate org.hibernate.AnnotationException: @OneToOne or @ManyToOne on <class> references an unknown entity: <class>

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm receiving Hibernate Exception like on Title. I've found that the common problem is the entity doesn't list on hibernate configuration file. But in my case, I've type the class name on hibernate configuration file.

Here is snippet of my code :

### Jenis.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "JENIS", schema = "APP")
public class Jenis implements java.io.Serializable {
private int id;
private int cloudid;
private String nama_jenis;

private List<Item> items;

public Jenis() {
}

...

 @OneToMany(mappedBy="jenis", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
 public List<Item> getItems() {
 return items;
 }

 public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
 this.items = items;
 }

}
```

### Item.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ITEM", schema = "APP")
public class Item implements java.io.Serializable {
    private Jenis jenis;

...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "JENIS")
    public Jenis getJenis() {
        return jenis;
    }

    public void setJenis(Jenis jenis) {
        this.jenis = jenis;
    }
...
```

### hibernate.cfg.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate 
     Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"

"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory name="">

    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect
    </property>
    <property name="connection.pool_size">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

    ....

    <mapping class="com.mypackage.beans.Jenis" />
    <mapping class="com.mypackage.beans.Item" />

    ....

</session-factory>
 </hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: It seems @Id is missing in the entity try to add in Jenis, or annotation is there ?

Comment: @Id annotation is there, but i didn't write on code above :)

Comment: Annotations works well I created the tables by myself using the metadata, It sounds obvious but classes are in the correct packages?

Comment: both classes are in the correct and same packages.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate wants primary keys in every table. Be sure that you have @ID annotations for your both tables

Comment: I already have primary keys (@Id annotation) on both my classes